# Is it possible to have random straight lines

Tags: java, random, jframe

As of right now I have a program that randomly generates a line that goes in all possible directions and terminates when it hits the edge of the circle or square.

Is it possible for me to have random lines that do NOT go diagonally? So it would essentially look like a game of snake and not random scribbles?

I'll paste the entire code so you understand whats going on.

```
     import java.util.Scanner;
     import java.util.Random;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class ABP {
      private static final Scanner CONSOLE = new Scanner(System.in);

      public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Lab 7 written by Devin Tuchsen");
        int rad = promptIntWithRange("Please enter the circle's radius (50-400 pixels): ", 50, 400);

        boolean cont = true;
        Color color = null;
        while(cont) {
          String colorStr = promptString("Please enter the color of the circle (green [g] or blue [b]): ");
          if(matchesChoice(colorStr, "green")) {
            color = Color.GREEN;
            cont = false;
          }
          else if(matchesChoice(colorStr, "blue")) {
            color = Color.BLUE;
            cont = false;
          }
          else {
            System.err.println("ERROR: \"" + colorStr + 
                               "\" is an invalid choice. Please enter \"green\", \"blue\", \"g\", or \"b\" (Not case-sensitive).");
          }
        }

        DrawingPanel panel = new DrawingPanel(rad * 2 + 32, rad * 2 + 32);
        Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(color);
        g.drawRect(16,16,rad * 2,rad * 2);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);

        int x = 16 + rad;
        int y = 16 + rad;
        g.drawLine(x,y,x,y);
        Random rand = new Random();
        int dir = 0;
        int cycles = 0;
        while(pointInsideCircle(x,y,rad+16,rad+16,rad)) {
          dir = rand.nextInt(4);
          switch(dir) {
            case 0:
              g.drawLine(x,--y,x,y);
              break;
            case 1:
              g.drawLine(++x,y,x,y);
              break;
            case 2:
              g.drawLine(x,++y,x,y);
              break;
            case 3:
              g.drawLine(--x,y,x,y);
              break;
          }
          cycles++;
          panel.sleep(1);
        }
        System.out.println("After " + cycles + " steps, the walk is finished.");
      }

      private static String promptString(String prompt) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        String str = CONSOLE.nextLine();
        if(str.length() == 0)
          str = CONSOLE.nextLine();
        return str;

      }

      private static int promptIntWithRange(String prompt, int min, int max) {
        int n = 0;
        boolean cont = true;

        while(cont) {
          System.out.print(prompt);
          if(CONSOLE.hasNextInt()) {
            n = CONSOLE.nextInt();
            if(n >= min && n <= max)
              cont = false;
            else
              //Handle errors where the user enters an integer outside the range
              System.err.println("ERROR: " + n + " is not between " + min + " and " + max + ".");
          }
          else {
            //Handle errors where the user enters something besides an int
            String str = CONSOLE.nextLine();

            //This check avoids posting an error with an empty string (leftover data in RAM)
            if(str.length() == 0)
              str = CONSOLE.nextLine();

            if (str.length() >= 22 && str.toLowerCase().substring(0,22).equals("open the pod bay doors"))
              System.err.println("I'm sorry, Dave. I'm afraid I can't do that.");
            else
              System.err.println("ERROR: \"" + str + "\" is not an integer value.");
          }
        }
        return n;
      }

      private static boolean matchesChoice(String str1, String str2) {
        str1 = str1.toLowerCase().trim();
        str2 = str2.toLowerCase().trim();
        if(str1.length() > 1)
          return str1.equals(str2);
        else if(str1.length() == 1)
          return str1.charAt(0) == str2.charAt(0);
        else
          return false;
      }

      private static boolean pointInsideCircle(int x, int y, int cx, int cy, int r) {
        return Math.pow(x-cx,2) + Math.pow(y-cy,2) < Math.pow(r,2);
      }
      }
```

Draw class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class DrawingPanel implements ActionListener {
    private static final int DELAY = 100;  // delay between repaints in millis
    private static final boolean PRETTY = false;  // true to anti-alias

    private int width, height;    // dimensions of window frame
    private JFrame frame;         // overall window frame
    private JPanel panel;         // overall drawing surface
    private BufferedImage image;  // remembers drawing commands
    private Graphics2D g2;        // graphics context for painting
    private JLabel statusBar;     // status bar showing mouse position

    // construct a drawing panel of given width and height enclosed in a window
    public DrawingPanel(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        statusBar = new JLabel(" ");
        statusBar.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

        panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 0, 0));
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));

        // listen to mouse movement
        MouseInputAdapter listener = new MouseInputAdapter() {
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                statusBar.setText("(" + e.getX() + ", " + e.getY() + ")");
            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                statusBar.setText(" ");
            }
        };
        panel.addMouseListener(listener);
        panel.addMouseMotionListener(listener);

        g2 = (Graphics2D)image.getGraphics();
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        if (PRETTY) {
            g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.1f));
        }

        frame = new JFrame("Drawing Panel");
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.getContentPane().add(statusBar, "South");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        toFront();

        // repaint timer so that the screen will update
        new Timer(DELAY, this).start();
    }

    // used for an internal timer that keeps repainting
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        panel.repaint();
    }

    // obtain the Graphics object to draw on the panel
    public Graphics2D getGraphics() {
        return g2;
    }

    // set the background color of the drawing panel
    public void setBackground(Color c) {
        panel.setBackground(c);
    }

    // show or hide the drawing panel on the screen
    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        frame.setVisible(visible);
    }

    // makes the program pause for the given amount of time,
    // allowing for animation
    public void sleep(int millis) {
        panel.repaint();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }

    // makes drawing panel become the frontmost window on the screen
    public void toFront() {
        frame.toFront();
    }
}
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Please, be a little more specific

Comment: Do you want a line that could change into multiple random directions, or what?

Comment: @ravensgo thats exactly what I want. Imagine a piece of graph paper, the line I want would be able to essentially go one block in a random direction at a time.

Comment: @Anton see above comment

Comment: @UriD.Charles provide us with some code. It is hard to understand what do you want to change

Comment: Toss a coin to decide whether your line will go horizontal or vertical. If it ended up being horizontal, then draw your line by only changing the X coordinate. If it ended up being vertical, only change the Y coordinate. I might have understood you wrong though.

Comment: We're all asking for clarification which suggests that your question confuses us. Since you're asking about image generation, posting an image of what you are trying to achieve as well as your best code attempt will help greatly. Since you don't have enough reputation to post an image, post a link to an image you've uploaded somewhere (not a link to a web page, but rather to the actual image), and we'll upload the image for you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels http://i.imgur.com/ZzJG2ne.png?1 so I just want the lines to be straight in every possible direction and not be able to go diagonally.

Comment: Thanks for the image, and I've posted it. It appears to be a fractal. Now regarding, `"I just want the lines to be straight in every possible direction and not be able to go diagonally"` -- this confuses me since diagonal **is** a possible direction and the first part of your statement states that you want the lines to go in all possible directions. Please clarify.

Comment: yes it is possible in any and every programming language

Answer (score -1):

I will just give you a few idea. I hope, i understand you clearly ;

Square has X unit length on every edge. So you can give restriction with this criterion. And you can apply this idea with thinking circles radius R while creating random straight lines(not diagonally) in this step you can use vectors ,for square (1,1)(1,2)(1,3) first x vector point is must be same for not diagonally(just the opposite for y). If line is longer or equal than squares X or circle's R then you can terminate your step.